# SVG filter is not always applied

Tags: reactjs, svg, svg-filters

I have this small website: https://retro-tetris.onrender.com/

I use svg to create bubble screen effect. The problem is the effect not working on load or if you reload page with Ctrl+F5. If you reload page regularly the effect becomes applied. I of course want it to be always applied. Do you have an idea why is this happening?

Also it appears to never work for Firefox but it somewhat works for Chrome. I use Chrome anyway.

Here what it looks like when filter is applied:
[image]

Here what it looks like when filter is not applied:
[image]

Heres react-ts code: https://github.com/fhgaha/tetris/blob/master/src/components/crt/CRT.tsx

And this is the fragment with filter and svg usage:

```
const CRT = (props: CRTProps) => {
    return (
        <div className={st.crt}>
            <img className={st['crt-frame']} src="img/crt_green_mask.png" alt="crt_green_mask.png"></img>
            <div className={st['crt-content']}>
                <div id={st.filters}>
                    <svg
                        id="svg-root" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                        width="381" height="166" z-index="-1"
                    >
                        <defs>
                            <filter
                                id="SphereMapTest"
                                filterUnits="objectBoundingBox"
                                x="-0.3" y="-1.3"
                                width="1.6" height="3.5"
                            >
                                <feImage
                                    id="mapa"
                                    result="Map"
                                    xlinkHref="img/sphere_wide_1.png"
                                ></feImage>
                                <feDisplacementMap
                                    id="despMap"
                                    in="SourceGraphic" in2="map"
                                    scale="100"
                                    xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G"
                                ></feDisplacementMap>
                            </filter>
                        </defs>
                    </svg>
                </div>

                <div id={st.content}>
                    {props.children}
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: There is a typo in your filter definition. feImage has `result="Map"`, but feDisplacementMap calls `in2="map"`. SVG is always XML-conformant and therefor case-sensitive.

Comment: there is a typo but fixing that typo did not fix the issue

Comment: It looks ok and should work, but one thing that you might try is adding x/y/width/height attributes to feImage. [It may be positioning the feImage at the filter origin (-30%, -130%)]